# Centering fixed position does not work on internet explorer

Tags: html, css

I'm failing to center fixed position on internet explorer (On internet explorer 11 does not work didn't tested on older versions) my current css code is:

```
.banner {
position: fixed;
max-width:1180px !important;
z-index:9999;
top: 0px;
background: #000 !important;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
```

On mozila firefox and google chrome it works properly.

Edit: I have fixed the issue by editing the code like this:

```
 .banner {
    position: fixed;
    width:1180px !important;
    z-index:9999;
    top: 0px;
    background: #000 !important;
    left: 0;
    margin:0 auto;
    right: 0;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you can have left and right both set at 0 can you? I believe IE has some issues with position fixed

Comment: When I did left and right position set to 0 it started working on firefox with chrome until than it didn't work anywhere :/

Comment: If it's a full width div, you should use margin auto instead I think

Comment: Which part of your CSS is intended to center?

Comment: 1. Its not full width 2. on Mozilla and chrome left:0 and right:0 does the trick and that div is centered

Comment: @showdev Thank you very much! What I did to fix this : I have changed max-width:1180px  to width:1180px and it fixed also I was afraid that it will be not responsive but other code does the trick and its responsive also margin:0 auto was included by other div so I didn't include that. Anyway thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
.banner{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

for transform you have to add vendor prefixes for each browser, but should work